# How to do logging without a logging framework package dependecy?

Tags: java, logging

I have a Utility package where it makes no sense to have `log4j` as a dependency, however there are some static methods where I would still like to do some logging.

I don't wish to do the following:

- pass a logger in as a parameter
- have the logger as a dependency
- throw exceptions for things that aren't exceptions (think INFO or WARN level logging)

Is there anyway I can do logging without having a logger as a dependency of the package, but it still use log4j when its on the classpath.

Comment: @MadProgrammer - will it still use log4j when its on the classpath?

Comment: What dependency management framework are you using?  Maven, but default, for example, won't include dependencies directly in the resulting build product.  Netbeans can allow you to define a project as a "Library" with the same result.  You still need `log4j` in your "dependency" list, so it will compile, but it won't have a direct dependency within the final jar and will rely on the fact that the `ClassLoader` can find it...

Answer (score 0):

You can check if log4j is on the classpath with the following:

```
Class.forName("org.apache.log4j.Logger");
```

If you get the `Class` back without exceptions, you can proceed to create a logger and use it.

Here's a complete example class which takes this approach. Note that you still need log4j to compile your class because you're referencing the log4j `Logger` but you can use the code with or without log4j on the classpath.

```
class YourUtil {

    private static final Logger LOGGER;
    static {
        Class<?> clazz = null;
        try {
            clazz = Class.forName("org.apache.log4j.Logger");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {}

        LOGGER = clazz == null ? null : Logger.getLogger("com.foo.YourUtil");
    }

    public static void doSomething() {
        // To log something:
        if (LOGGER != null)
            LOGGER.info("Logging using log4j.");
    }
}
```